# event handlers in WPF mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF MVVM. Recently I came across a document where for the button click event he has the following cs code and xaml code. Now lets say I want the keyUp event for the button then how do I handle it.

```
<Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,40,0,0" Name="btnUpdate" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
                 Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommad}"  />


private ICommand mUpdater;
         public ICommand UpdateCommand
         {
             get
             {
                 if (mUpdater == null)
                     mUpdater = new Updater();
                 return mUpdater;
             }
             set
             {
                 mUpdater = value;
             }
         }

        private class Updater : ICommand
         {
             #region ICommand Members

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
             {
                 return true;
             }

            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            public void Execute(object parameter)
             {

            }

            #endregion
         }
```

Comment: why you need keyup event for a button ?

Comment: Lets say if we have a requirement such that we need to handle the Keyup event. Not only keyUp but some event other than click, then how do we go about doing it.

Comment: you have to handle that in xaml.cs, from there you call the viewmodel or BL classes

Comment: You are looking for EventToCommand. Here is a tutorial on how to use it http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Please have a look at this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/       Can I pass the command parameer as CommandParameter={"Binding SelectedItem.User, ElementName=UserGrid"}. In short I want to pass the entire business object of selected value of the list view to the object parameter of the execute method... Can I do it

Comment: CommandParameter is a bindable property. I think you'd have to do CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=UserGrid}" and then cast the SelectedItem to a User in your Command method.

Comment: @LeeO. Don't you think that it might be a bit confusing, to have Commands with event-names? e.g. `ClosingCommand`, `InitializedCommand` and stuff? I know, functionally this works pretty well, but semantically its nonsense. Also does this bloat your XAML, in comparison to a normal bindingexpression. Do you know if there's now better solutions for the same behavior?

Comment: Brian Lagunas actually suggests not putting anything into the xaml.cs, it breaks the MVVM organizational structure.